# Were there restrictions on German refugees entering the US during World War II?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, nazi-germany, immigration

It is known that many Germans (especially Jews) migrated to the US during WW2.

Now, I was wondering about the formal requirements for refugees to be admitted into the US at that time. Was any German citizen able to move to the US or were there severe restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

With very few exceptions, immigration into the United States had been largely shut down by the Johnson–Reed Act in 1924. Nearly all the European refugees who came to the United States before 1941 did so illegally, sneaking into the country, usually through Canada, or by overstaying specialized visas, such as visas granted to journalists. After December 1941 all of Europe and the United States was heavily militarized and it was very difficult to cross borders at all, even illegally, so anyone who failed to get out before that time was likely to be stuck unless they were rich and very resourceful.